# Dynamic Labels | VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, label

For every item it finds I want to add a few labels with details like prices and quantity.
I've made something and it only places them once and just rewrites everything. I assume the problem would be because I'm not returning, but if that is the case, I have no clue how to I could do that in this situation. Here's my code

```vb
Function addShoppingCartinfo() As System.Windows.Forms.Label

        Dim lblQuantityCart As New System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Dim lblPriceCart As New System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Dim lblProductNameCart As New System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Dim lblIndexInCart As New System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Dim lblDescriptionCart As New System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Dim lblSubtotalPriceInCart As New System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Dim lblTotalPriceInCart As New System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Dim var_Y As Integer = 47
        Dim var_YTotal As Integer = 104
        Dim var_YDescription As Integer = 72


        For Each ItemInCart In list_Cart
            For Each id In arr_ID
                If id = ItemInCart Then

                    var_AmountInCart += 1

                    var_Y += var_AmountInCart
                    var_YTotal += var_AmountInCart
                    var_YDescription += var_AmountInCart


                    var_QuantityIndex = list_Cart.IndexOf(ItemInCart)
                    var_WinkelWagenIndex = Array.IndexOf(arr_ID, id)
                    var_SubTotalPrice = arr_Prices(var_WinkelWagenIndex) * list_Quantity(var_QuantityIndex)

                    list_Prices.Add(var_SubTotalPrice)


                    WinkelWagen.Controls.Add(lblQuantityCart)
                    WinkelWagen.Controls.Add(lblPriceCart)
                    WinkelWagen.Controls.Add(lblProductNameCart)
                    WinkelWagen.Controls.Add(lblIndexInCart)
                    WinkelWagen.Controls.Add(lblDescriptionCart)
                    WinkelWagen.Controls.Add(lblSubtotalPriceInCart)
                    WinkelWagen.Controls.Add(lblTotalPriceInCart)

                    For Each price In list_Prices
                        var_TotalPrice += price
                    Next

                    lblQuantityCart.Text = list_Quantity(var_QuantityIndex)
                    lblQuantityCart.Location = New Point(539, var_Y)


                    lblIndexInCart.Text = var_AmountInCart
                    lblIndexInCart.Location = New Point(494, var_Y)
                    lblIndexInCart.Visible = False


                    lblPriceCart.Text = "SRD " & arr_Prices(var_WinkelWagenIndex)
                    lblPriceCart.Location = New Point(494, var_Y)


                    lblDescriptionCart.Text = arr_Names(var_WinkelWagenIndex)
                    lblDescriptionCart.Location = New Point(240, var_Y)


                    lblSubtotalPriceInCart.Text = "SRD" & var_SubTotalPrice
                    lblSubtotalPriceInCart.Location = New Point(640, var_Y)

                    lblProductNameCart.Text = arr_Names(var_WinkelWagenIndex)
                    lblProductNameCart.Location = New Point(113, var_Y)

                End If

            Next

        Next
        lblTotalPriceInCart.Text = "SRD" & var_TotalPrice
        lblTotalPriceInCart.Location = New Point(640, var_YTotal * var_AmountInCart)

        Debug.WriteLine("this has " & var_AmountInCart & " Quantity")



    End Function
```

[When I've got 2 items it does this. (Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1K18.png)

Comment: Think about the logic. You want 7 `Labels` for each item in the cart, right? Where are you doing things relating to the current item in the cart? Inside the loop, right? Where are you creating the `Labels`? Outside the loop. Where should you be creating them `Labels` if you want them to apply to the current item specifically?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to be positioning all these `Labels` explicitly. If you really want to use `Labels` then use a `TableLayoutPanel`. You can add the appropriate number of columns and then just add each `Label` to the panel and let it worry about the layout. It can also grow downwards automatically. Alternatively, just use a `DataGridView` and make it raed-only.

Comment: Regarding the creating labels, now that you've said Id say within the loop. About the datagridview and tablelayoutpanel; I'll look into those. It'll be tomorrow when I can try it all out

Comment: I've put the the creation of the labels inside the loop, and tested it. It still only creates one row of labels

Comment: I've put the the creation of the labels inside the loop, and tested it. It still only creates one row of labels

Comment: If the creation of the `Labels` is inside the loop and only one row of `Labels` is created then that would mean that the loop is only executed once. Have you actually debugged and confirmed that that's the case? Have you debugged at all? You need to set a breakpoint at the top of the code, step through it line by line and examine the state at each step to see what's actually happening and you need to do that before posting a question. Do that now, post what you find and also post your new code, so that we can see if there's anything obviously wrong with it.